# Setting value in JList

Tags: java, jlist

Yes, setting value to a JList, know that. But i want to know is there an easy way to implement custom JList on which setSelectedValue() will not raise event to to inform attached listeners. I want to keep it quiet :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a custom `javax.swing.ListSelectionModel` that doesn't fire events and assign an instance to your `javax.swing.JList`.